# When to use type alias and interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript1.4

Typescript recently introduce type alias in its 1.4 release.

It seems like interface and type alias both kind of server the same purpose - defining a custom type. I am wondering if there's a standard/best practice on when should we use type alias or interface?

Answer (score 1):

- With `type` you cannot declare an anonymous *generic* type and alias
  it.
- With `interface` you cannot declare a top-level union, like with alias `type ElementIdOrElement = string | HTMLElement`.

I use types as a local measure to make code spanning few dozen lines more readable.

I use interfaces for everything else, that spans more than one file.